# What's most common way to wish for the weekend?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

What is the most common phrase for wishing good things for for people about the weekend? I thought about something like "have a nice weekend" or "have a sweet weekend" etc.

Comment: If someone says they're going to do something which is a lot of fun on the weekend, you could exclaim "Sweet!" but to wish someone a sweet weekend would be a little unusual.

Answer (score 3):

*Have a **good** weekend* or *Have a **nice** weekend* are [by far the most common idiomatic ways to say this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Have%20a%20*%20weekend&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2CHave%20a%20%2A%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BHave%20a%20nice%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHave%20a%20good%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHave%20a%20great%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHave%20a%20pleasant%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHave%20a%20lovely%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHave%20a%20wonderful%20weekend%3B%2Cc0).  Any other option is so much less common that it's notable just for being different.

You can technically use any adjective that means "good" or "enjoyable" - have a *great* weekend, an *awesome* weekend, a *fantastic* weekend - but *sweet* is not an idiomatic replacement for *good*; if someone said "Have a sweet weekend!" to this native US English speaker, it would strike me as distinctly unusual.